# Clearing Browser Local Storage will affect the hybrid app data?

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

I tried to install an sencha touch app in my samsung s duos. I have doubt whether if i try to clear browser cache will it affect the local storage of my app. But it was not so. Every phonegap application is running on webkit, even after empty the cache of browser by clearing localstorage still its work fine. May be this question seems like stupid, but i like to know the answer. Whether i just clearing the cache of external browser(Chrome) not the internal webkit. Is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because you save data in LocalStorage and not in the cache. If you clear the browser cache all websites which have data in LocalStorage retain this data, too, so there is no conflict with LocalStorage and Cache.

Comment: And another question is clearing the local storage of external browser will affect of my internal app local storage?

Comment: I've checked that out on iOS and if you delete all safari data the localstorage in the phonegap app does not become erased. If you open Sencha Touch app in Safari and add to homescreen the LocalStorage doesn't become erased either. If you use sencha touch app only through Safari however, the LocalStorage becomes erased.